# dict.setObject does not work for own struct

Tags: dictionary, struct

What's needed to get this code running?

```
dict.setObject(gReplacements, forKey: "gReplacements")
```

I created my own plist within a dictionary. I could load and save with different types of data. Only when I try to save my own struct (s. below). I get an error message:

"Cannot invoke "setObject"  with an argument of type ('[FromTo], forKey: String)'

Definition:

```
struct FromTo {
    var From = String()
    var To   = String()
}

var gReplacements : [FromTo] = [ FromTo(From: "X", To: "Y") ]
```

Any idea?

Comment: What language? Should be tagged.